# local storage - show modal once on wp page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, local-storage

I dont know if this is a wp centered issue, but Ive done this before and can't get it to work in a WordPress environment. Basically, I want to show a modal dialog box on the first visit to the site, and not on following visits in same session.

```
function slideIn() {
    jQuery('#overlay').fadeIn('fast');
}

function slideOut () {
    jQuery('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
}
jQuery(function() {
    //local storage lasts until cache cleared
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('slideState') != 'shown'){
        slideIn();
        sessionStorage.setItem('slideState','shown');
    }
    jQuery(document).on('click', '#popInClose', function(e){
        slideOut();
        e.preventDefault();
        sessionStorage.setItem('slideState','shown');
    });
});
```

When I load page for first time, modal displays as expected. When I close it and either reload the page or go to another page, it is displaying again, which is not desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set some defaults and work from them. Something like this will work.

```
    var state = (sessionStorage.getItem('seen') == 'seen') ? 'seen' : 'unseen'; 
    if (state == 'seen') { 
        slideOut(); //Or whatever to hide the modal
    }
    else { 
        slideIn(); //Or whatever to show the modal
        sessionStorage.setItem('seen','seen'); //Set state as seen
    }
```